# Show function/statement declaration after selecting closing brace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

I'm wondering if you can do something similar to this functionality (available with Zend Studio 5.1) in Eclipse. There is an image of it in action here: http://tinypic.com/r/2d1pao1/6

As you can see, it doesn't just put a box around the starting brace like Eclipse does, it actually shows you the declaration. This is especially handy when you have a really long declaration and don't want to scroll up and find its beginning.

Comment: Note that Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 M7 - New and Noteworthy" introduced Bracket matching improvements in Java editor. I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Update May 2012)

The latest "[Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 M7 - New and Noteworthy](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.2M7-201205031800/eclipse-news-M7.html)" introduced [Bracket matching improvements in Java editor](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.2M7-201205031800/eclipse-news-M7.html#bracket-matching):

> You can hover over a closing curly brace and see the source near the matching opening brace in a hover.
>   This is helpful when you want to see the code near the start of a long code block.
>   The hover also tells the number of lines in the code block.

[image: bracket-hover]

> The hover is also useful to temporarily 'highlight' a short code block.

[image: bracket-hover for short function]

---

Original answer (December 2009)

Actually, you already have a variant of that with the **outline view**

If you click anywhere in a function (end of curly brace or anywhere else), the outline view will... outline the relevant function where you are in.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/outlineView.png))</sub>

---

Otherwise, you need a plugin like [**Eclipse Source Helper**](http://hexapixel.com/projects/sourcehelper)
(update site: http://www.hexapixel.com/update)

[image]