# How to open a file in Eclipse AND jump to a specific line?

Tags: windows, eclipse

I can open a file in exclipse, but is there any syntax to jump to a specific line?

VI can do this by

```
vi -c LINE filename
```

Comment: I can not understand what you mean by syntax,but keyboard shortcut CTRL+L will open a popup and you can enter line number there.

Comment: @Adi: CTRL+L would work only when "Editing Text", i.e if the file is *already* opened...

Comment: @Von He mentioned 'I can open a file in eclipse', I guess he already know how to open.

Comment: @Adi: I interpreted it as: "how to open file (*not yet* opened)  *directly* to a specified line.

Answer (score 44):

Not exactly the right answer, but for Java file, you can use the package explorer, or the [outline view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910836/show-function-statement-declaration-after-selecting-closing-brace-in-eclipse/1910922#1910922), useful to [select a group of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838432/eclipse-can-you-put-your-cursor-on-all-lines/1838557#1838557)) and open the file to the line matching a Java element (class, method, variable, ...)

[image: Eclipse open]

Once the file is already opened, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is the way to go to a line of the currently edited file, as [Adi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11092/adi) mentions in the comment.

Comment: @abel: courtesy of http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm FastStone Capture (not free, but worth every penny)

Comment: That screenshot is diabolical

Comment: @VonC you're telling us that you actually paid for the $45 family license so you can take prettier screenshots?

Comment: @krispy It was not 45$ at the time I purchased a license some 6 or 7 years ago, but it was worth every penny for the usage I had and still have of this software.

Answer (score 12):

Finally fixed!!

On Windows:

```
eclipsec.exe -name Eclipse --launcher.openFile %USERPROFILE%\workspace\MyClass.java:50
```

On Linux/Mac:

```
eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.openFile ~/workspace/MyClass.java:50
```

Answer (score 10):

Only tested on MARS:

**Preferences > Keys > "Open from Clipboard"**

Assign key binding.

1. Copy i.e. log entry in format *Main.java:1*
2. Press chosen key binding
3. voilà

In latest Version [Oxygen] key was <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

Comment: This should be the accepted solution as its inbuilt into eclipse and allows for easy navigation fro m a log stack trace to the class file

Answer (score 8):

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Open Resource) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Open Type, for classes only)
2. Type the name / the start of the name / the first letters of a camel case name
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Go to line)

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. For me it works on Windows as simple as

```
eclipse.exe path\filename.ext:42
```

(I was actually looking for a consistent solution across IDEs.
[Pycharm offers `pycharm.exe path:number` as well](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-files-from-command-line.html) but it does not seem to work :/)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
eclipse.exe file.txt:22
```

for newer versions of eclipse, and

```
eclipse.exe file.txt+178
```

for older ones.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @raho's response, the complete menu path is: 
Window  -> Preferences -> General -> [Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sR3a.png)

This won't work on c++ as far as I can tell.

(I'm using Oxygen 4.7.1a)